# How to get synonyms from definitions using Bayes algorithm

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, java

I work on a project: an online dictionary where the user can find definitions of a word he's looking for.
My supervisor asked us to add synonyms using machine learning. He recommend us to use Bayes algorithm.
but I don't see how to do this, how to put every word in a category and make probabilities.

Please how can I use this algorithm? knowing that my project is in java.

Thanks, for any suggestions or opinions.

Comment: Perhaps you should asks your supervisor. They're supposed to help you.

Comment: If the fact that your project is in Java makes a difference, then this question doesn't belong here. However, I suspect it makes little difference.

Comment: Your question is rather open-ended. What prevents you from using the Google synonym service, for example? How can you tell whether two given words are synonyms? A lot of information is missing. I'm not sure a Bayes classifier is even relevant here, but in any case, why restrict yourself?